Does calling non-const mem. fun. on const object via non-const ref obtained via const_cast invoke UB only if the fun actually modifies the object?
In short, I'm asking whether the following code invokes UB only if /* body */ does indeed change the value of i, or also if it doesn't, by virtue of calling the non-const maybeChange member function on a const object.
// header.hpp
struct Foo {
  int i;
  void maybeChange();
};

void work(Foo const& foo);

// foo.cpp
#include "header.hpp"
void Foo::maybeChange() {
  /* body */
}

// work.cpp
#include "header.hpp"
void work(Foo const& foo) {
  const_cast<Foo&>(foo).maybeChange();
}

// main.cpp
#include "header.hpp"
Foo const foo{6};

int main() {
  work(foo);
}

I do see that the problem exists in case the modification really takes place, because that violates a legit assumption the compiler can make, i.e. that the foo global object doesn't change.
But on the other hand, http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4 shows no example of calling non-const member function on const object to which const was const_casted away, but that doesn't actually modify it, like in my example above. It shows trivial examples like
const int* ciq = new const int (3);     // initialized as required
int* iq = const_cast<int*>(ciq);        // cast required
*iq = 4;                                // undefined behavior: modifies a const object

where the last line does truly modify the object *ciq.

AFAIK its the modification of a const object is the only thing that is actually UB.  If no modification happens there should not be any UB.

You say "const_cast" required... NO that cast should (almost) never be in your code.  And you are usually setting yourself up to shout yourself in the foot. The only time I ever need a const_cast is if you C++ interface is const correct and you're calling a legacy "C" api that only accept non-const pointers (and even then it is more safe to make a copy of your data). In all other cases you are basically breaking a contract. But yes it is UB, and fairly easy to explain. A compiler/linker may opt to store constants in ROM and there is no valid way to write to that.

@PepijnKramer um, the "cast required" comes from the language specification. It is saying that the cast is required in order to produce an int*. This is a language lawyer question, not an api design question

The examples are all triviall because strictly speaking, only scalar objects can even be accessed for reads or writes, and so the member function call itself is neither.

@PepijnKramer, my question is about what happens if a non-const member function that doesn't actual modify its *this is called on a const object to which the const has been const-casted away. Please, re-read the question and feel free to try improve it if not clear.

My apologies, I have misunderstood the actual question ;)

It is indeed UB if your program modifies a constant object. From the link that you have shared - Any attempt to modify ([expr.ass], [expr.post.incr], [expr.pre.incr]) a const object ([basic.type.qualifier]) during its lifetime ([basic.life]) results in undefined behavior. [emphasis mine].

Calling the function itself is not UB. There is only UB if you try to modify the value of one of the members or the object itself.
And if foo wasn't declared const, then there wouldn't even be UB if the function modified the object or its members.
It is exactly the same as for explicit function parameters. You can view the operand on the left-hand side of . as an implicit argument to an implicit parameter of type Foo&. It mostly behaves the same way as other arguments with that interpretation.
As referenced in your question, [dcl.type.cv]/4 is the only rule that results in UB due to constness and nothing in your example violates it. That there doesn't happen to be a suitable example for this in the standard doesn't change anything. If you think that it may help understanding, you could suggest adding such an example via editorial issue here, although I don't know the policies regarding examples or such suggestions.

do note that Q's tagged language lawyer are seeking quotes from the standard to back up the answer.

@NathanOliver There is nothing to quote, because there simply is no rule being violated.
